# an isomorphism between discrete modules over profinite groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-cohomology

the notations follow Serre's famous book Galois cohomology. Suppose $H$ is an open subgroup of a profinite group $G$. 
Denote by $M^H _G (\mathbb{Z})$ the induced module of the trivial $H$-module $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $A$ be a discrete $G$-module. The exercise is: prove $M^H _G (\mathbb{Z})\otimes_\mathbb{Z} A \simeq M^H _G (A)$ as $G$-modules.

So I find the induced module $M^H _G (\mathbb{Z})$ is a free Abelian group because each element in it is constant on the (right) cosets of $H$. Choose a set of representatives $x_i, i=1,...,n$. Then as an Abelian group $M^H _G (\mathbb{Z})$ has a dual basis $\phi_i, \phi_i (h x_i)=\delta_{ij}, \forall h\in H$.

Now I have to construct $f: M^H _G (\mathbb{Z})\otimes_\mathbb{Z} A \longrightarrow M^H _G (A)$, so this means to determine $f(\phi_i \otimes a)$. But $A$ isn't necessarily a discrete $G$-module, I have no idea how to define this, can anyone give me some help or hint? thanks!

Comment: $G = \bigcup_j g_j H,\quad M_G^H(A) = \bigcup_j [g_jH] A$ where $g.( [g_jH] a) = [gg_jH](g.a)$. Then $\Bbb{Z}\otimes_\Bbb{Z} A=A$ as $G$-module so that $M_G^H(\Bbb{Z})\otimes_\Bbb{Z} A=\bigcup_j [g_jH] \Bbb{Z}\otimes_\Bbb{Z} A=\bigcup_j [g_jH] A=M_G^H(A)$.

Comment: oh yes,  the cohomology uses discrete module coefficient and is assumed to be continuous.  can u explain in detail for me?  why the first equality of the induced module holds?  here $A$ isn't with trivial action in generalis the bracket just an index or it means the action of the coset on $A$?